# Webpack - resolve-url-loader does not resolve paths correctly

Tags: webpack, sass, resolve-url-loader

I have a problem with setting up `resolve-url-loader` correctly in my webpack config. It does not seem to resolve paths in `scss` files at all.

Here is my project folder structure:

```
├───config
│   └───jest
├───public
│   └───assets
│       ├───css
│       ├───fonts
│       ├───images
│       │   ├───background
│       │   ├───icons
│       │   ├───illustration
│       │   ├───logo
│       │   └───projects
│       │       ├───one
│       │       └───two
│       ├───js
│       └───scss
│           ├───blog
│           ├───common
│           ├───default
│           ├───elements
│           ├───header
│           └───template
├───scripts
└───src
    ├───component
    │   ├───common
    │   ├───footer
    │   ├───header
    │   └───slider
    ├───elements
    │   ├───blog
    │   ├───common
    │   ├───portfolio
    │   ├───projects
    │   └───tab
    └───home
```

Below you will find how `webpack.config.js` looks like. It's kind of complex but I tried to hide all code chunks that I think are irrelevant for solving this issue. In general the loaders chain in `use` method is created by `getStyleLoaders` function defined at the beginning of the file. If `preProcessor` is identified as `sass-loader` then additionally the `resolve-url-loader` is added. The problem is that when looking at `resolve-url-loader`'s debug, it seems that it does not resolve url's from scss files in `public` folder. The only debug logs that I get are as follows:

`Resolve-url-loader` debug log:

```
resolve-url-loader: ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css: ./ajax-loader.gif
  ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick
  FOUND
resolve-url-loader: ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css: ./fonts/slick.eot
  ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick
  FOUND
resolve-url-loader: ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css: ./fonts/slick.woff
  ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick
  FOUND
resolve-url-loader: ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css: ./fonts/slick.ttf
  ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick
  FOUND
resolve-url-loader: ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css: ./fonts/slick.svg
  ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick
```

I have some url links defined in `scss` files that I don't see in `debug's' log.
What am I doing wrong?

`webpack.config.js` details:

```js
'use strict';

/*some plugins*/
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const safePostCssParser = require('postcss-safe-parser');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
/*some plugins*/
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const paths = require('./paths');
const modules = require('./modules');
/*some plugins*/

const postcssNormalize = require('postcss-normalize');

const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'true';
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  // Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
  // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
  // In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
  const publicPath = isEnvProduction
    ? paths.servedPath
    : isEnvDevelopment && '/';
  const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';

  const publicUrl = isEnvProduction
    ? publicPath.slice(0, -1)
    : isEnvDevelopment && '';
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
  const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: '../../' } : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            }),
            postcssNormalize(),
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
        if (preProcessor === "sass-loader") {
            loaders.push({
                loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
                options: cssOptions,
            })
        }

      loaders.push({
        loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
        options: {
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      });
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: [/*...*/].filter(Boolean),
    output: {/*...*/},
    optimization: {/*...*/},
    resolve: {/*...*/},
    resolveLoader: {/*...*/},
    module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        {
          /*es-lint loader*/
        },
        {
          oneOf: [
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            {/*babel-loader*/},
        },
        {/*babel-loader*/},
        {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),
              sideEffects: true,
        },
        {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              }),
        },
        {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              sideEffects: true,
        },
        {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: true,
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
        },
        {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [/*...*/].filter(Boolean),
    node: {/*...*/},
    performance: false,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It turned out that I had to define `url`'s differently in scss files.

Comment: differently how? Could you explain how you solved it?